# Cantilever Beam - Maximum Shear of the Beam

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, classical-mechanics, elasticity

> A cantilever beam $3\ \text{m}$ long is subjected to a moment of $10\ \text{kNm}$ at the free end. Find the maximum shear of the beam.

The answer is "There is no vertical load, shear is zero"

How come? The shear should be sliding upward at the end of the wall and downward to the free end.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "no vertical load, the shear is zero" because the moment on the end of the cantilever beam only creates a bending moment on the beam which results in only a normal force on the beam and no shear force.

Answer (score 0):

The direction of the moment is important. There must have been a diagram with this problem? One would assume from the answer that the moment is acting solely horizontally.

Comment: no diagram is given, just word problem